# How to reduce boilerplate code for web api calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

I am working with a ASP.NET MVC website and ASP.NET Web Api service. Current architecture looks like this

```
Browser => UI website => Web Api service => databases
```

The argument to split UI and Web Api was so that we can have several different UIs (Web, Mobile, Desktop, watches, etc) all calling intermediate service to get data. However, when I need to add a new api call i need to add quite a bit of plumbing boilerplate code (+ boilerplate tests which I dislike even more).

```
Browser => ajax 
    UI  => controller and web api proxy client
Web API => controller and repository
           database
```

I am thinking, it would have been easier to combine web api with UI, as I won't need to write additional controllers and proxy to call it, however I am not sure if this is the right way to go. We have about 20 controllers and 100 api calls written in C#. I am interested to know how other people use web api together with UI projects.

**Should I merge Web Api project with UI project and what are the pros and cons of doing so?**